# trying to get date to MM/DD/YYY

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have a coding using sqldeveloper under Oracle database using a student database, PowerSchool:

```
PS_CUSTOMFIELDS.getStudentsCF(s.id,'CA_LastIEPDate') AnnDate
```

This is a custom field, ca_lastIEPdate getting info from Students table and put in a column under `AnnDate` as `AnnualDate` and got `12-AUG-2018`.  I tried to add `to_Char( ,'MM/DD/YYYY')` within the coding but could not make it out of it.

Comment: Is AnnualDate a date or text?

Comment: whats the result/error?

Answer (score 1):

[PS_CUSTOMFIELDS.getStudentsCF](https://www.fccsc.k12.in.us/fccsc/PSU_Docs/1%20Resources/ps7x_pscustomfields_api_guide.pdf) returns `varchar2`.

Convert to date, then convert back to the expected format.

```
select to_char(to_date(PS_CUSTOMFIELDS.getStudentsCF(s.id,'CA_LastIEPDate'), 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') AnnDate ...
```